# Arquillian tests for an application with Seam 2.2.1 with JSF 1.2 and Richfaces 3.3.3 with managed JBoss 7.2

Tags: richfaces, jsf-1.2, jboss-arquillian, seam2

I am working with legacy code based on:

- Seam 2.2.1
- JSF 1.2
- Richfaces 3.3.3

The app itself is running fine on a Wildfly 9.0.2, with some dependencies such as JSF 1.2 being used instead of the Wildfly 9.0.2 Defaults.
The Arquillian configuration is running on a managed JBoss 7.2

Before moving this app to a newer technology stack, I need to write an extensive test Suite. I would like to use Arquillian for this purpose.

I managed to get some things to work already. However, for some tests I need to create an Identity and have Seam recognize me (the test) as a logged in user. This is where I am stuck.

Whatever I try, I get this exception:

```
ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/ISMS_Tool]] (http-/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:8180-2) 
JBWEB000211: Session event listener threw exception: 
org.jboss.seam.InstantiationException: Could not instantiate Seam component: 
org.jboss.seam.security.ruleBasedPermissionResolver
at org.jboss.seam.Component.newInstance(Component.java:2170) 
[jboss-seam-2.2.1.Final.jar:2.2.1.Final]
at org.jboss.seam.contexts.Contexts.startup(Contexts.java:304) [jboss-seam-2.2.1.Final.jar:2.2.1.Final]

Caused by: org.jboss.seam.InstantiationException: Could not instantiate Seam component: securityRules
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.drools.base.evaluators.EvaluatorRegistry.addEvaluatorDefinition(EvaluatorRegistry.java:155) [drools-core-5.6.0.Final.jar:5.6.0.Final]
```

[I am mostly using code from this repository]https://github.com/omidp/seam/tree/master/seam-integration-tests/src/test/java/org/jboss/seam/test/integration/security

The SecurityTest.java is what I'm trying to get to work here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will solve the problem above. I hope it may be useful for other developers working with legacy applications.

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
@ArquillianSuiteDeployment
public class seamIntegrationTest  {

private AssetAction assetAction;
private EntityManager entityManager;
private User user;

@Deployment
public static Archive<?> createTestArchive() {
    MavenResolverSystem resolver = Maven.resolver();
    resolver.loadPomFromFile("pom.xml");
    return ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "my.war")
            .addPackages(true, "de.abc.ui")
            .addPackages(true, "de.abc")
            .addAsResource("META-INF/test-persistence.xml", "META-INF/persistence.xml")
            .addAsResource("META-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml", "META-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml")
            .addAsResource("META-INF/jaxws-endpoint-config.xml", "META-INF/jaxws-endpoint-config.xml")
            .addAsResource("META-INF/jboss-webservices.xml", "META-INF/jboss-webservices.xml")
            .addAsResource("de/abc/tool/webservice/handler/ws_security_handler.xml")
            .addAsResource("components.properties")
            .addAsResource("security.drl")
            .addAsResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "seam.properties")
            .addAsWebInfResource("components.xml")
            .setWebXML("web.xml")
            .addAsLibraries(
                    resolver.loadPomFromFile("pom.xml").importRuntimeAndTestDependencies().resolve().withTransitivity().asFile());
}



@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    MockFacesContext mfc = new MockFacesContext(new MockExternalContext(), new MockApplication());
    UIViewRoot viewRoot = mock(UIViewRoot.class);
    when(viewRoot.findComponent(anyString())).thenReturn(mock(UIForm.class));
    mfc.setViewRoot(viewRoot);

    Method m = ReflectionUtils.findMethod(FacesContext.class, "setCurrentInstance", FacesContext.class);
    m.setAccessible(true);
    m.invoke(null, mfc);

    Credentials credentials = new Credentials();
    credentials.setUsername("user");
    credentials.setPassword("password");// these should be an existing user in the database
    credentials.setInitialized(true);

    Principal principal = new Principal() {
        @Override
        public String getName() {
            return "principalname";
        }
    };

    ExtendedIdentity identity = new ExtendedIdentity();
    identity.create();

    Field c = ReflectionUtils.findField(ExtendedIdentity.class, "credentials");
    c.setAccessible(true);
    ReflectionUtils.setField(c, identity, credentials);

    c = ReflectionUtils.findField(ExtendedIdentity.class, "principal");
    c.setAccessible(true);
    ReflectionUtils.setField(c, identity, principal);

    identity.login();
    Contexts.getSessionContext().set(Component.getComponentName(Identity.class), identity);

    List<User> users = entityManager.createNamedQuery(User.Q_getUserByUserName)
            .setParameter("username", "password")
            .getResultList();
    if (!users.isEmpty()) {
        user = users.get(0);
        Contexts.getSessionContext().set("loginUser", user);
        for (Role role : user.getRoles()) {
            identity.addRole(role.getRolename());
        }
    }

}

// This is the dialog that can only be accessed when a user is successfully logged in:
@Test
public void openCreateNewDialog() throws Exception {

    assetAction.setAssetId(126);
    assetAction.setAsset(entityManager.find(Asset.class, 126));

    assetAction.openNewChildAssetDialog();
    String result = assetAction.saveNewChildAsset();
}
```

}